# NameError: name 'C' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Can anyone tell me, why C is not defined?
I expect an output in the end for C.

[image]

Comment: It means just what it says. `c` isn't defined. It's defined inside your `taxes` function, but not outside of it.

Comment: Because `c` only exists within the scope of the function, not in the global scope where you try to access it. Although you return the value stored against c, the _name_ is not accessible outside of the function.

Comment: By the way, do not put in a link to an image of your code. Copy your code into the question.

Comment: Also, please do not post images of code. There is no reason you couldn't copy the code into the question.

Comment: You can fix this by simply changing the line `taxes(x)` to `c = taxes(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Here c is not defined because c is a local variable that can be assessed only inside taxes function.

You can try the below code :

```
c = taxes(x)
```

In this way, you assign the value 1000 or whatever your function return to c. And your code won't give an error